# ORDER BY UPPER (column) is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.6

With MySQL 5.6, given the following table structure:

```
mysql> describe groups;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following data in the

```
`groups` table:

mysql> select id, name from groups;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | some-users       |
|  2 | SOME-ADMINS      |
|  3 | customers-group1 |
|  4 | customers-group2 |
|  5 | customers-group3 |
+----+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following query is badly sorted in MySQL (whereas it works correctly in at least PostgreSQL, Oracle, and MSSQL):

```
mysql> select id, name from groups order by upper(name);
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  3 | customers-group1 |
|  4 | customers-group2 |
|  5 | customers-group3 |
|  1 | some-users       |
|  2 | SOME-ADMINS      |
+----+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would expect :

`SOME-ADMINS` to appear before `some-users`, as is the case with other DB vendors.

Is this a bug of MySQL?

Comment: Try LOWER, too. And check if the `-` is actually the same character.

Comment: the upper shouldn't be in the SELECT ?

Comment: The ``-`` is the same character, ``LOWER`` does not work better, and it does not work any better if ``UPPER(name)`` is in the SELECT. But thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Can you do a self join: select g1.id, g1.name, g2.id, g2.name from groups g1 join groups g2 on upper(g1.name) < upper(g2.name)

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem in http://sqlfiddle.com/ using MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, it is case insensitive but you can make it case sensitive using BINARY :

> On character type columns, sorting—like all other comparison operations—is normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion. This means that the order is undefined for columns that are identical except for their case. You can force a case-sensitive sort for a column by using BINARY like so: ORDER BY BINARY col_name.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the pointer to the doc. So I have to use ``UPPER`` to remove case sensitivity of the order, but ``BINARY`` to get back a sane order. It does not look very cross-vendor, but it is correct for MySQL.

Comment: I don't see how this explains why "u" is sorted before "a".

Comment: It doesn't explain the result. UPPER should not be used for this purpose according to the documentation. There is no indication, as far as I've read, as to what to expect when using UPPER in an ORDER BY clause.The main point is that if you need case sensitivity ordering when using mysql, you should use BINARY.